# Can we remove the [convert] -> [imagemagick-convert] synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

In response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141963/can-we-remove-the-convert-tag), the useless [convert](/questions/tagged/convert) tag was semi-burninated, but made a synonym for [imagemagick-convert](/questions/tagged/imagemagick-convert).

Now, the [imagemagick-convert](/questions/tagged/imagemagick-convert) is getting slapped onto any random question posted by someone trying to convert something to something else, which is certainly worse than having the useless tag to begin with.

It appears to me that 14 of the 58 questions currently with the tag actually have anything to do with ImageMagick.

Comment: Ooh, ooh, can we blacklist it instead?  Pretty please?  With cherries on top?

Answer (score 1):

I removed [convert](/questions/tagged/convert) as a synonym of [imagemagic-convert](/questions/tagged/imagemagic-convert) and made it a synonym of [base-conversion](/questions/tagged/base-conversion) instead.  I'll keep an eye on that tag for a bit.  We may need to just blacklist it.

Comment: I removed the tag from a ton of questions just now, and the vast majority were about either translating code from one programming language to another or typecasting; I think just 2 were about base conversion.

Comment: @Wooble Thanks.  I'll ask in chat if someone on the Community Team can just blacklist it.